# Game theory -- Linear programming problem

Tags: linear-programming, game-theory

Can someone please help me with this question, I don't even know where to start.

[image]

For part bi) I think the answer is

$  minimise \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_{i} = \frac{1}{v} subject to   \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij} x_{i} \geq 1 $

don't know how to write the LP for player B?

And i have no idea how to do part (bii) Please could anyone help me with this part.

Comment: If A wants to maximize their minimum value, then B wants to minimize the maximum value (because that value is for A).

Comment: How do I get  $ p* = v(A^{T})^{-1}u $

Comment: Can you please post the problem as text (instead of pasting an image) so that future visitors can at least search for this question using a search engine?

Comment: I suspect that (b)(ii) may only hold for weakly completely mixed bimatrix games? https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82818138.pdf